# Laravel eloquent joining two tables override same column issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and payment_request

my user table screenshot as follows,

[image: user table]

and the payment_request table screenshot as follows,

[image]

I want to join payment_request table to user table using Laravel Eloquent.

Here is my code:-

```
$user_payment_request_list = PaymentRequest::join('currency','currency.id','=','payment_requests.currency_id')
->join('users','users.id','=','payment_requests.sender_id')
// ->join('users','users.id','=','payment_requests.receiver_id')
->where("sender_id", $id)
->get([
    'currency.name as currency_name',
    'payment_requests.amount',
    'payment_requests.status',
    'payment_requests.description',
    'payment_requests.sender_id',
    'users.name as sender_name',
    'users.name as receiver_name',
    'payment_requests.transaction_id',
    'payment_requests.branch_id',
    'payment_requests.created_at',
    'payment_requests.updated_at',
]);
```

I get the output where it overrides the receiver_id and give me same result from sender_id

[image]

Comment: We cant see your table structure avoid using images and include it as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$user_payment_request_list = PaymentRequest::join('currency','currency.id','=','payment_requests.currency_id')
            ->join('users as sender_user', 'sender_user.id','=','payment_requests.sender_id')
             ->join('users as receiver_user', 'receiver_user.id','=','payment_requests.receiver_id')
            ->get([
                'currency.name as currency_name',
                'payment_requests.amount',
                'payment_requests.status',
                'payment_requests.description',
                'payment_requests.sender_id',
                'sender_user.name as sender_name',
                'receiver_user.name as receiver_name',
                'payment_requests.transaction_id',
                'payment_requests.branch_id',
                'payment_requests.created_at',
                'payment_requests.updated_at',
            ])
            ->where("sender_id", $id)
            ->get();
```

I use SQL `AS` command for rename the User table.